# Detect CPU during boot

Tags: linux, scripting, boot, grub, grub2

I like to be able to detect the cpuinfo from during boot using grub2.

Can this be done?
What function should I call?
Is there a manual that lists all of the function available to the grub2 env?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [cpuid](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/cpuid.html#cpuid) command.  There is a [manual section](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Commands.html#Commands) listing all commands.